# Storing EC2 AMI in different regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

My Server is running on AWS EC2 (Tokyo region) and I have an AMI in same region. But I want to run different servers in different regions with same configuration as my tokyo instance have.

Is it possible store AMI in common place and access from different regions (or) should I copy the AMIs in all different regions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Copying an AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html). Amazon will do all the hard work for you.